# Limits and Continuity - One sided limits question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> For the functions $$f(x)= \begin{cases}0, &x=0 \\ 1, & x=1 \\ 2, & x \not= 0,1 \end{cases}   g(x)=\begin{cases}0, &x=0\\ 1+|x|, &x \not=0 \end{cases}$$
>
> determine $f(g(0))$ and $f(\lim_{x \to 0}g(x))$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f(g(x))$

This is my attempt:

$g(0) = 0$ therefore, $f(g(0))=f(0)=0$

$f(\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)) = f(1+|x|) = 2$

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(0) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First case is correct.

$\lim_{x \to 0 }g(x)=1$

$f(\lim_{x \to 0 }g(x)) = f(1) = 1$

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0}f((1+|x|)) $

because $1+|x|$ is always striclty greater than 1,

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x))=2 $

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: writing
$$
f(\lim_{x\to0}g(x))=f(1+|x|)
$$
is wrong. Better, try and compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}(1+|x|)=1
$$
so $f(\lim_{x\to0}g(x))=f(1)=1$.

On the other hand,
$$
f(g(x))=\begin{cases}
0 & g(x)=0 \\
1 & g(x)=1 \\
2 & g(x)\ne0,g(x)\ne1
\end{cases}
$$
We have $g(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$ and $g(x)\ne1$ everywhere. So
$$
f(g(x))=\begin{cases}
0 & x=0 \\
2 & x\ne0
\end{cases}
$$
and therefore $\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))=2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(g(x))\neq \lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$$

cause $$g((0-\eta,0+\eta))=\{2\}\not \subset (1-\alpha,1+\alpha)$$

the chain rule doesn't work.

Comment: No, I won't delete your posts for you. .  You post an answer? Live with it. Commit to it.  If you made an error, you'll simply have to sit on it until you can delete it yourself. Don't vandalize your answer by wiping it out, followed by "please help me to..." The next time I see you vandalizing an answer and then begging for deletion ",  I'll begin flagging such posts for moderator attention.  They have access to your delete record, Yes, to all of the posts you've deleted or were deleted by others.

Comment: If you can erase your answer by editing, you can edit in a correction. But don't leave your trash for us to clean up.  Besides, when you erase an answer to ask a totally irrelevant question, that is defined, precisely, as vandalism to one's own post.

Comment: And it is your responsibility; if you know you cannot delete from mobile, then you need to start thinking seriously about the quality of your answers **before** you post them. If you change your mind later, you'll have to allow time in your day to edit to correct them. I know you can edit. So do so.

Comment: Is it possible to delete from PC.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, You can delete any answer you've written from a PC.

Comment: @amWhy That's fine. good night.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, your behaviour has really annoyed a few people (including me, I have cleaned up the mess after you more than 10 times, I guess) so much that [a question addressing it has been asked on Meta.MSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25299/cant-self-delete-unanswered-question-or-answer-from-mobile-device). While many of your posts here are useful, vandalizing your own posts and asking others to delete them on a regular basis is *really* annoying.

Comment: @AlexM. Ok. if i disturb, i will stop to use my phone.